# Asp.net Hosted in IIS getting the status code returned from server 500

Tags: asp.net

I have hosted my ASp.net Project in IIS in Client Place. while working the user gets an error 
like

> The Page xxxx IP Says
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 500

Please help how to solve this..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tested in your Staging/Dev envt and it is working there. Check out this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

Meanwhile, also check your web.config file and disable the server trace if it is enabled.